# How to retrieve value from the other table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

let me explain the scenario..!!
i have used devise for the authentication. Devise table in the database is named as "user". Now i have another table named as "book" which stores the user id.

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :books do |t|
  t.integer "user_id", :limit =>5
  t.string "book_name", :limit => 50
  t.integer "edition", :limit => 5
  t.string "author", :limit => 30
  t.string "branch", :limit => 30
  t.string "publisher", :limit => 50
  t.integer "year", :limit => 10     
  t.text "details"
  t.timestamps
end
add_index :books, "user_id"
end
end
```

I store the userid in the book table so that i cant display that this book is available to this user. But showing only the user id on the book page doesnt make sense so i made another table named as s_user,

```
class CreateSUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :s_users do |t|
  t.integer "user_id", :limit => 5
  t.string "fullname", :limit => 25            
  t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "hashed_password", :limit => 40
  t.string "salt", :limit => 40
  t.string "address",:limit => 25
  t.text "details"
  t.timestamps
end
add_index :s_users, "user_id"
end
end
```

which stores the complete information of the user like his/her name, address, phone no. 
The relationship which i made between book and user is mant to many and one to one to user to s_user.
So i am not getting how to display the user's information which is stored in the s_user table.
what i did i m writing here:
In the controller

```
@books = Book.all
```

In the views

```
                     <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
                        <th>Book Name</th>
                        <th>Year </th> 
                        <th>Owner id</th>
                        <th>Owner Details</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <% @books.each do |b| %>                                        
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= b.id%></td>
                        <td><%= b.book_name%></td>
                        <td><%= b.year%></td>
                        <td><%= b.user_id%></td>

                    </tr>                                               
                    <%end%>
```

Now under the owner details i want to display the user details. which i am not getting how to display?

Answer (score 0):

see this [relatinship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

if you give relationship `belongs_to` and `has_many`

for example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

now you can access by using `@user.books` you get all the books of that particular user

for create books you can use

```
@user.books.build
```

so that in your books table user_id comes automatically

you can also get user detail from book, for example

```
@user = @book.user
```

Comment: I think u didnt get the actual scenario. Actually when the user(shopkeeper) sign's in, the user's id is saved automatically to the book table while adding a new book(i ve provided shopkeeper add,delete,edit privileges to his book's record). My question is how can i retrieve the user details (i.e SUser table's data) through this user_id( which is saved in book table n it is created by devise).

Comment: I also want to remind you that devise's table is different and shopkeeper's table is different. Also there is a one to one relationship between these two tables. And many to many relationship between table and user table(devise).

Comment: i have thought to do it like this
`v = Book.user_id`
`a = SUser.find_by_user_id(v)`
`b = a.address`